# Syntax error in INSERT INTO command while using pyodbc

Tags: pandas, ms-access, pyodbc

This is the code where syntax error occurs

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date

Today = date.today()
Today = Today.strftime('%d-%m-%y')

NSE_Deli = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Daily Data/NSE_Deliverables.csv")
def append_NSE_Deliverables():
    for row in NSE_Deli.itertuples():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl1A_Deliverable_NSE (Symbol,Series,Volume,DeliVolume,Deli%,`Timestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
            row[1],
            row[2],
            row[3],
            row[4],
            row[5],
            Today
            )
```

The error returned is,

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl1A_Deliverable_NSE (Symbol,Series,Volume,DeliVolume,Deli%,`Timestamp`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)",
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLExecDirectW)')

The code given below with the same syntax didn't return any problem

```
NSE_Bhav = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Daily Data/cm05MAY2021bhav.csv")
def append_NSE_Bhavcopy():
    for row in NSE_Bhav.itertuples():
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl1A_Bhavcopy_NSE (Symbol,Series,Open,High,Low,Close,Last,PrevClose,Volume,Turnover,`Timestamp`,TotalTrades,ISIN) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",
            row[1], 
            row[2], 
            row[3],
            row[4],
            row[5],
            row[6],
            row[7],
            row[8],
            row[9],
            row[10],
            row[11],
            row[12],
            row[13]
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

The column name `Deli%` needs to be quoted. Access ODBC will accept backquotes, but square brackets are more commonly used in Microsoft's dialects of SQL

```py
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tbl1A_Deliverable_NSE ([Symbol],[Series],[Volume],[DeliVolume],[Deli%],[Timestamp]) VALUES …
```

Since you're using pandas you may want to consider using the [sqlalchemy-access](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-access/) dialect for SQLAlchemy. (I am the maintainer of that dialect.)