# Pyodbc Syntax Error in the instruction INSERT INTO

Tags: python, ms-access, pyodbc

i'm getting the same error as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67417141/syntax-error-in-insert-into-command-while-using-pyodbc) question here, however, trying that solution of enclosing the column names with square brackets gave no results.

pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement. (-3502) (SQLPrepare)")

Below is the code. And yes, im fully aware that the database structure does not follow any best practice whatsoever, but i cannot refactor that.

```
conn_str = (r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
            r'DBQ=C:\temp\b.accdb;')
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
cursor = conn.cursor()
insert = 'INSERT INTO [GENERALITA\' FERMATA] ([COD_Fermata],[Linee],[Azienda],[Fermata_Corrispondente],[Distanza tra fermate corrispondenti],[COD_Corrisp],[Denominazione],[Riferimento],[Direzione],[Su piazzola esterna],[Su carreggiata],[Distanza da curve (m)],[Distanza da dossi (m)],[Distanza da incroci o intersezioni (m)],[Distanza da attraversamento pedonale (m)],[Coord_Y],[Coord_X],[Zona],[Foto 1],[Foto 2],[Foto 3],[Foto 4],[Foto 5],[Display a messaggio variabile],[Panchine],[Tabella orari],[Pensilina],[Porta biciclette],[QR code o altri sistemi statici],[Pubblicità],[Punto interscambio bus],[Note interscambio],[Altri operatori],[Parcheggio],[Divieto di sorpasso],[Incrocio semaforizzato],[Isola salvagente],[Illuminazione],[Passaggio pedonale],[Strisce gialle tratteggiate],[Scritta gialla \"bus\"],[Segnaletica verticale],[Sosta bus corsia riservata],[Spazio sosta pedoni],[Limiti di velocità],[Persenza marciapiede],[Rampa marciapiede],[Pulsante semaforo],[Corrimano],[Banchina dispositivi di protezione],[Pista ciclo-pedonale],[Segnalazione non-vedenti],[Note_Generalita],[Note_Posizione],[Note_Comfort],[Note_Sicurezza]) 
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
params =(codFerm,ln,aznd,ferCor, disFerCor,codCor,descr,rif, drz, suPiazEs, sucar, distCrv, distDoss, distIncr, distAttPed, coordY, coordX, zn, f1,f2,f3,f4,f5, dsplMess,panc,tabOr,pens,prtBc,qr,pub,ptScmbBus,ntInt,altrOp,park,noPass,semfr,isl,illum,passPed,strGia,scrGia,senVert,sostCors,sostPed,limVel,marPed,ramPed,pulsSem,crrMn,bncPrt,pstCicPed,senNvd,notGen,notPos,notCom,notSic)
cursor.execute (insert, params)
cursor.commit()
```

and this is the insert statement printed out.

```
INSERT INTO [GENERALITA' FERMATA] ([COD_Fermata],[Linee],[Azienda],[Fermata_Corrispondente],[Distanza tra fermate corrispondenti],[COD_Corrisp],[Denominazione],[Riferimento],[Direzione],[Su piazzola esterna],[Su carreggiata],[Distanza da curve (m)],[Distanza da dossi (m)],[Distanza da incroci o intersezioni (m)],[Distanza da attraversamento pedonale (m)],[Coord_Y],[Coord_X],[Zona],[Foto 1],[Foto 2],[Foto 3],[Foto 4],[Foto 5],[Display a messaggio variabile],[Panchine],[Tabella orari],[Pensilina],[Porta biciclette],[QR code o altri sistemi statici],[Pubblicità],[Punto interscambio bus],[Note interscambio],[Altri operatori],[Parcheggio],[Divieto di sorpasso],[Incrocio semaforizzato],[Isola salvagente],[Illuminazione],[Passaggio pedonale],[Strisce gialle tratteggiate],[Scritta gialla "bus"],[Segnaletica verticale],[Sosta bus corsia riservata],[Spazio sosta pedoni],[Limiti di velocità],[Persenza marciapiede],[Rampa marciapiede],[Pulsante semaforo],[Corrimano],[Banchina dispositivi di protezione],[Pista ciclo-pedonale],[Segnalazione non-vedenti],[Note_Generalita],[Note_Posizione],[Note_Comfort],[Note_Sicurezza]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)('4', None, None, False, None, None, 'Torino Rossetto', None, None, False, False, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, '.\\FOTO TOTALI\\4(1).jpg', '.\\FOTO TOTALI\\4(2).jpg', '.\\FOTO TOTALI\\4(3).jpg', '.\\FOTO TOTALI\\4(4).jpg', '.\\FOTO TOTALI\\4(5).jpg', False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, None, None, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, 0, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, None, None, None, None)
```

The number of columns, question marks and parameters is correct, 56 in all cases, but i keep getting that error.

EDIT: I've enclosed the table name in square brackets as well, and both with and without escaping the quotes on "bus" does not work.

Comment: Where is your closing `'`?

Comment: That isn't an INSERT statement.

Comment: You're right! i did miss it while copying, and it may lead to a wrong answer. Fixed it, thanks!
@ScottHunter care to elaborate?

Comment: An INSERT statement isn't just a list of values, which is what you printed out.

Comment: This question is a trainwreck. You're right as well. And posting it here now i think i see the problem.

Comment: The `insert` variable doesn't have `[]` around the table name. How is that being printed out?

Answer (score 0):

I have turned your `INSERT` into a `CREATE TABLE`, there are two things to note:

- the table name can/should also be enclosed into square brackets because of the space and apostrophe, `GENERALITA\' FERMATA` to `[GENERALITA' FERMATA]`
- the column `[Scritta gialla \"bus\"]` is created as `Scritta gialla \"bus\"` and not `Scritta gialla "bus"` which I think you might be trying to access

```sql
CREATE TABLE [GENERALITA' FERMATA] (
    [COD_Fermata] BIT,
    [Linee] BIT,
    [Azienda] BIT,
    [Fermata_Corrispondente] BIT,
    [Distanza tra fermate corrispondenti] BIT,
    [COD_Corrisp] BIT,
    [Denominazione] BIT,
    [Riferimento] BIT,
    [Direzione] BIT,
    [Su piazzola esterna] BIT,
    [Su carreggiata] BIT,
    [Distanza da curve (m)] BIT,
    [Distanza da dossi (m)] BIT,
    [Distanza da incroci o intersezioni (m)] BIT,
    [Distanza da attraversamento pedonale (m)] BIT,
    [Coord_Y] BIT,
    [Coord_X] BIT,
    [Zona] BIT,
    [Foto 1] BIT,
    [Foto 2] BIT,
    [Foto 3] BIT,
    [Foto 4] BIT,
    [Foto 5] BIT,
    [Display a messaggio variabile] BIT,
    [Panchine] BIT,
    [Tabella orari] BIT,
    [Pensilina] BIT,
    [Porta biciclette] BIT,
    [QR code o altri sistemi statici] BIT,
    [Pubblicità] BIT,
    [Punto interscambio bus] BIT,
    [Note interscambio] BIT,
    [Altri operatori] BIT,
    [Parcheggio] BIT,
    [Divieto di sorpasso] BIT,
    [Incrocio semaforizzato] BIT,
    [Isola salvagente] BIT,
    [Illuminazione] BIT,
    [Passaggio pedonale] BIT,
    [Strisce gialle tratteggiate] BIT,
    [Scritta gialla \"bus\"] BIT,
    [Segnaletica verticale] BIT,
    [Sosta bus corsia riservata] BIT,
    [Spazio sosta pedoni] BIT,
    [Limiti di velocità] BIT,
    [Persenza marciapiede] BIT,
    [Rampa marciapiede] BIT,
    [Pulsante semaforo] BIT,
    [Corrimano] BIT,
    [Banchina dispositivi di protezione] BIT,
    [Pista ciclo-pedonale] BIT,
    [Segnalazione non-vedenti] BIT,
    [Note_Generalita] BIT,
    [Note_Posizione] BIT,
    [Note_Comfort] BIT,
    [Note_Sicurezza] BIT)
```

Check columns:

```sql
EXEC SP_COLUMNS [GENERALITA' FERMATA]
```

Just to confirm, this insert works (with `Scritta gialla \"bus\"` created above):

```sql
INSERT INTO [GENERALITA' FERMATA] (
    [COD_Fermata],
    [Linee],
    [Azienda],
    [Fermata_Corrispondente],
    [Distanza tra fermate corrispondenti],
    [COD_Corrisp],
    [Denominazione],
    [Riferimento],
    [Direzione],
    [Su piazzola esterna],
    [Su carreggiata],
    [Distanza da curve (m)],
    [Distanza da dossi (m)],
    [Distanza da incroci o intersezioni (m)],
    [Distanza da attraversamento pedonale (m)],
    [Coord_Y],
    [Coord_X],
    [Zona],
    [Foto 1],
    [Foto 2],
    [Foto 3],
    [Foto 4],
    [Foto 5],
    [Display a messaggio variabile],
    [Panchine],
    [Tabella orari],
    [Pensilina],
    [Porta biciclette],
    [QR code o altri sistemi statici],
    [Pubblicità],
    [Punto interscambio bus],
    [Note interscambio],
    [Altri operatori],
    [Parcheggio],
    [Divieto di sorpasso],
    [Incrocio semaforizzato],
    [Isola salvagente],
    [Illuminazione],
    [Passaggio pedonale],
    [Strisce gialle tratteggiate],
    [Scritta gialla \"bus\"],
    [Segnaletica verticale],
    [Sosta bus corsia riservata],
    [Spazio sosta pedoni],
    [Limiti di velocità],
    [Persenza marciapiede],
    [Rampa marciapiede],
    [Pulsante semaforo],
    [Corrimano],
    [Banchina dispositivi di protezione],
    [Pista ciclo-pedonale],
    [Segnalazione non-vedenti],
    [Note_Generalita],
    [Note_Posizione],
    [Note_Comfort],
    [Note_Sicurezza])
VALUES(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

NB. this is tested against SQL Server 2019 since I do not have access to an Access DB, but should be compatible.